# I have some doubts regarding Docker

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am new to Docker. I feel its easy to use docker for cross platform applications. But i have some concerns regarding the storage and security.

1. Where are docker images that were pulled are stored in the local machine?
   I have observed that my C drive space is reducing but i could not able to find where the images are being stored.
2. We need to mount the source code of our application. Is it safe to mount the files to docker. Are they secured when we are using it?

Any Help is appreciated 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Docker is everything but cross-platform, that was never the point. Windows and macOS support is provided by a virtual machine that runs Linux. Regarding your 2nd question, secured _from what_?

Comment: [What is docker image location on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250222/what-is-docker-image-location-on-windows-10)

Comment: Secured from the third party to steal our code

Comment: This is all a bit vague, but I think what you are asking is can people from outside our LAN steal code via a docker container. In 99.99% of standard cases, I would say *NO*. If you installed some sort of file-sharing service on your docker container with no security, exposed the docker container on your host, and then port-forwarded external traffic to your host machine, it would become possible to anyone who knew you had actually gone and done that. In any real-world cases, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Things in a Docker container are just as secure/insecure as in the host system.